# error in Calculation of SUM of a column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There is column named stationeryqtyrecd in table tblstationerystock.I want to print the total value of stationeryqtyrecd for a particular quantity (say pen).but my query showing error.my query is

```
  <?php
include('includes/config.php');

$sql = "
SELECT SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) as total 
  from tblstationerystock 
 where stationerytype = :type
"; 
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':type', "pen", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$total=$results->total();



echo $total;

?>
```

Comment: You bind a parameter isread which is not in your query

Comment: @juergend I corrected it in code  still not working

Comment: What error? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @jameson2012 can you explain or write the full code please .I removed brackets from total now it has error Notice: Trying to get property 'total' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\admin\test.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = "
       SELECT SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) AS total 
       FROM tblstationerystock 
       WHERE stationerytype = :type"; 

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

//you cannot pass values to bindParam, so you need to use a variable,
//or use bindValue
    $query->bindValue(':type', "pen", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

//you are only selecting a single value, so you don't need to fetchAll, or even fetch,
//just use fetchColumn
    $total = $query->fetchColumn();

echo $total;
```

Comment: i've tested this code and it works correctly.  If you are showing no data and no php errors you most likely have an issue with your sql query.  I suggest you do some debugging, and check all your column names

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
include('includes/config.php');

$type='pen';
$sql = "SELECT SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) as total from tblstationerystock where stationerytype = :type"; 
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':type', $type);
$query->execute();
if($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    print($row->total);
}
```